# Covers of $Z^k$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, gn.general-topology

This is a question related to  [covers of $Z^\infty$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37449/covers-of-z-infty). Is it possible to cover $Z^k$, $k>1$, with the $l_1$-metric by a constant (not depending on $k$) number of collections of subsets $U^0,...,U^c$ where each $U^i$ consists of uniformly bounded $\lambda$-disjoint sets $U_j^i$ ("$\lambda$-disjoint" means $dist(U_j^i, U_l^i)\ge \lambda$ for every $i,j\not=l$), $\lambda$ is fixed, $>1$?

In https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3868, we show (Lemma 3.7) that for $k<2^{\lambda-1}$, the minimal $c$ is $k$. The question is what happens for $k\ge 2^{\lambda-1}$.

Update: The answer is not known even if $\lambda=3$.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify the question. Can the constant implicit in "uniformly bounded" depend on $k$? I'm guessing that if it can't, you're left with your previous question.


Comment: Yes, the "uniformly bounded" constant can depend on $k$. The number of collections of 4-disjoint sets should be independent on $k$.

Comment: In line 4 there is a typo, where it should read $\lambda$ instead of $4$.

Comment: Actually for $\lambda=4$ the answer is also unknown.